# How can I initialize int output in Dictionary TryGetValue

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I opened my old project today, then found out that I have an errors, but as I remember the last time I opened it , It has no error and running, here is the codes:

```
Dictionary<string, int> transactionItemDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows) {
                if (!transactionItemDictionary.ContainsKey(item["Description"].ToString())) {
                    transactionItemDictionary.Add(item["Description"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(item["Quantity"]));
                } else {
                    transactionItemDictionary.TryGetValue(item["Description"].ToString(), out int count);
                    transactionItemDictionary.Remove(item["Description"].ToString());
                    transactionItemDictionary.Add(item["Description"].ToString(), count + Convert.ToInt32(item["Quantity"]));
                }
            }
```

[image]

I checked other example online and this code is given as example.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring the `count` variable before the `TryGetValue` call:

```
int count;
transactionItemDictionary.TryGetValue(item["Description"].ToString(), out count);
```

As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#calling-a-method-with-an-out-argument) state:

> In C# 6 and earlier, you must declare a variable in a separate statement before you pass it as an out argument.

The syntax you are trying to use is available starting with C# 7.0.

Comment: Yes, I tried that already and it fixed my problem, I'm just curious why its not working now lol Thanks

Comment: @NicoTing maybe old version of VS? Which one do you use?

Comment: actually I used the same version of VS which is 2015, but I installed VS 2019 back then

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the whole `if` with a simple `=`:

```cs
foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows) {
    transactionItemDictionary[item["Description"].ToString()] = Convert.ToInt32(item["Quantity"]);
}
```

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-5.0#property-value) says:

> **TValue**
>
> The value associated with the specified key. If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a KeyNotFoundException, and a set operation creates a new element with the specified key.

Comment: Unless the old KeyValuePair may have been stored somewhere else in the program and you absolutely need to make sure to have a new instance.

Comment: Then use `Add` which will throw if the key has been added already.